# How to get parent and child page in menu and display in counter form [wordpress]

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, parent-child

Hi I'm trying to create a menu for my own template. Example:

```
Parent 1
- child 1
- child 2

Parent 2

Parent 3
```

When I'm on the Parent1 page, I want to display the Parent1, child1 and child 2, but in counter form. So, it would be like for example:

> 0    1    2

And when I'm on child1 or child2 page, it would display the same menu as above because they are subpages of Parent1. And when I'm on Parent2/Parent3 page, no menu should be shown.

I have tried using wp_list_pages, wp_get_nav_menu_items, wp_get_nav_menu_object and etc. I can't seem to get it done correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly 'counter form' means. Anyway, have a look at https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages#Parameters (and, more specifically, the `'child_of'` param). You could use that to determine if a page has children and then display the menu accordingly.
Like, if you wanted to show child page links only on pages that actually have children, you could set the menu depth based on the output of `get_pages( 'child_of' )`.